# JavaFX 11 jar not executable java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

I have been using JavaFX on JDK 8 for a few years. Now I wish to try to upgrade our JDK to OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11.

On Apache NetBeans 12.2 I tried the Maven Example and it runs fine on NetBeans (right click->RUN).

But I can't run it from jar file, not even from shell by using java -jar testJavaFX.jar

I always get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I have tried adding in RUN config vmOptions

```
--module-path %PATH_TO_FX%
--add-modules javafx.controls,primary.fxml
```

(also tried javafx.fxml and absolute path instead of %PATH_TO_FX%)

When I do this I can't even run it on NetBeans

I get error

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
Command execution failed.
```

or

```
    cd C:\Users\TCN\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testJavaFX; 
"JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot" cmd /c "\"
C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.2\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" 
-Dexec.args=\"--module-path \\\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\\lib\\\" 
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -classpath %classpathtestJavaFX.java 
-classpath %classpath testJavaFX.java 
-classpath %classpath javafx.controls ,primary.fxml 
-classpath %classpath javafx.controls ,javafx.fxml 
-classpath %classpath javafx.controls 
-classpath %classpath javafx.controls testJavaFX.java 
-classpath %classpath com.tradeconnex.testjavafx.App\" 
-Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\\bin\\java.exe\" 
-Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.2\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Prelease-profile process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec"

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I'm trying this on both Mac and Windows machines, the results are the same.

I guess the program cannot find javafx.

I've set PATH_TO_FX to C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib (tried both lib and bin with and without quotes "" and tried putting them on Path variable as well)

My JDK is jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot

My old jdk8 javafx projects won't run now either after I installed JDK11.

I tried adding all javafx jars from maven to my POM, again I can only run it from NetBeans.

Again the apps from JDK 8 and JDK11 both run fine in NetBeans but neither will run from jar or shell. The old JavaFX jars from jdk8 used to be executable now are not.

Does anyone have a solution, please?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>testJavaFX</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>testJavaFX</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <javafx.version>11</javafx.version>
    <mainClass>com.company.testjavafx.App</mainClass>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>testJavaFX</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.company.testjavafx.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.company.testjavafx.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                    <id>debug</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                    <id>ide-debug</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                    <id>ide-profile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is load all javafx modules as maven dependencies and use a Launcher class that extends your Main class and executes the main function. I've written an entire medium article regarding this. Check it out.

https://nikhiladigaz.medium.com/deploying-non-modular-javafx-applications-using-maven-and-launch4j-fb95b8ab0739

Also. You haven't mentioned if your app is modular or non-modular. Even if your app is modular this approach works but you will have to make necessary changes in your module-info file.

Comment: Thank you Nikhil for your help. I added a pom file on my question. I actually added javafx into my project and I did try a launch file that called the main class but it just said couldn't find the javafx Application class. Also all my old jdk 8 jar applications that were running fine before all stopped running after I installed JDK 11, even when I still keep older versions of JDK. I can still run them on NetBeans menu>RUN. I tried changing JAVA_HOME but no difference. Also the JavaFX example I got straight out of NetBeans Maven. There is a module-info.java file so It is a Modular program.

Comment: When I uninstalled JDK11, my old jars become executable again. But that doesn't help migrating to JDK 11.

Comment: I started with NetBeans new project  "FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype (Gluon)" - get an error "no manifest attribute" then I added "maven-jar-plugin" with manifest attribute - then got "no Application class" so I added "maven-dependency-plugin" to create "dependency-maven-plugin-markers" folder inside target but didn't help.